# Laravel eloquent wrapper for maria-db dynamic columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, mariadb

As far as i know which `MariaDb` has a `Dynamic columns` and data of this columns in database should be `blob`.

> The dynamic columns are stored inside a real blob column

in `MariaDb` sql commands we can use `CREATE_COLUMN` to create some column and `GET_COLUMN` to get some column from `blob`

for example:

inserting data:

```sql
INSERT INTO bird_sightings 
(human_id, time_seen, observations) 
VALUES
  (27, NOW(),
   COLUMN_CREATE('wing-shape','pointed', 
  'bill-shape','all-purpose', 'main-color','gray') );
```

get query from database:

```php
SELECT name_first AS 'Birder', 
DATE_FORMAT(time_seen, '%b %d') AS 'Date',
COLUMN_GET(observations, 'wing-shape' AS CHAR) AS 'Wings',
COLUMN_GET(observations, 'wingspan' AS INT) AS 'Span (cm)',
COLUMN_GET(observations, 'bill-shape' AS CHAR) AS 'Beak'
FROM bird_sightings
JOIN humans USING(human_id);
```

and now what i want to know? is any `Eloquent` wrapper for this structure, using like `ORM` with them? or how can i use with this structure in `Laravel`

Answer (score 0):

Without having tested this myself I think you can try adding the following in your model:

```
public function newEloquentBuilder($query) {
      $query->addSelect(DB::raw("COLUMN_GET(observations, 'wing-shape' AS CHAR)"));
      $query->addSelect(DB::raw("COLUMN_GET(observations, 'wingspan' AS CHAR)"));
      $query->addSelect(DB::raw("COLUMN_GET(observations, 'bill-shape' AS CHAR)"));
      return parent::newEloquentBuilder($query);    
}
```

If you want to ad-hoc get them for a particular query only you can just add the above selects in the query builder e.g.

```
$sighting = BirdSighting::selectRaw("name_first AS 'Birder', 
DATE_FORMAT(time_seen, '%b %d') AS 'Date',
COLUMN_GET(observations, 'wing-shape' AS CHAR) AS 'Wings',
COLUMN_GET(observations, 'wingspan' AS INT) AS 'Span (cm)',
COLUMN_GET(observations, 'bill-shape' AS CHAR) AS 'Beak'")->get()
```

Comment: could you help me after overriding `newEloquentBuilder` method how can i use that? how can i pass the `query` into that?

Comment: Whenever you do something like `BirdSighting::where(condition)` the method `newEloquentBuilder` should be called to create a new query builder, in those cases the new builder will be made with those additional selects so there shouldn't be anything more you need to do to get those columns in your model when you make queries